Visual Studio Community 2022: NuGet Package Manager not installing packages
I am using Visual Studio 2022. When I install a package, no error is shown, the green tick will appear and I can see the package name in the "Installed" tab. But no file is pushed to my project.

This may be due to some setup issues or issues with the NuGet package manager. Here are some possible solutions:
1: Re-add nuget.org: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings. Go into the package source, copy the details of nuget.org, delete nuget.org, then re-add nuget.org with the details you copied.
2: Select "Tools" > "Options" > "NuGet Package Manager" > "General" in Visual Studio, and then click "Clear All NuGet Cache(s)" to clear the cache.
3: Use the NuGet command line tool to install.
